# Dynamically increase the height of the div container

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have two div containers for which I have fixed the height and width. One of the containers holds the body of the blogpost and other holds the list of all the posts created. Since, body of a blogpost or list of posts can be larger than the size of their div container. So, I want to dynamically increase container's size when they exceed its size. How can I achieve it either using css or javascript?

css file

```
body {
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
}
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:100px;
    right:100px;
    bottom:50px;
}
#content {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:0;
    width:70%;
    height:550px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #282828 ;
    color:white;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#rightnav {
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    right:20px;
    width:275px;
    height:550px;
    background-color: #282828 ;
}
#rightnav p {
    margin:0px 0 10px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    color:#CCCCFF;
}
#rightnav h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin:0;
    color:#FF9900;
}
#rightnav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#posts {
    padding:0;
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#posts h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#posts p {
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
}
#content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: none;
    color:black;
}
```

base.html #every other html files inherit from this base file

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "container" style="clear:both;">
<div id = "content">
{% block post %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
<div id = "rightnav">
<h2>Popular Posts</h2>
{% block popular_posts %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

post.html #the template which deals with showing posts

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block post %}
{% load django_markdown %}
<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
{{ post.body|markdown }}
{% endblock %}
{% block popular_posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <a href = "/home/{{post.id}}"><p>{{ post.title }}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Marcanuy's answer, you have to remove the bottom:50px given to the #container div.

And by removing position:absolute from unwanted places will make your css neat. If you want to position your div side by side, you can use display:flex for your parent (#container) div.

EDIT: Have also removed the position:absolute property and have added margin:50px to make your div center-aligned. (You can also use padding property)

Refer : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imranking/j0cdp02n/)

```
#container {
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:100px;
 right:100px;
}

#content {
 padding:0;
 width:70%;
 min-height:550px;
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color: #282828 ;
 color:white;
}
#rightnav {
 width:275px;
 min-height:550px;
 background-color: #282828 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your *height* with *[min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)*, this will make your containers have **at least** the specified height, then they will grow and fit their content needs.

```
#rightnav {
    min-height:550px;
}
#content {
    min-height:550px;
}
```